# Request to API and waiting to answer

Tags: javascript

I need to send GET request `username=alison&date=2021` to file `file.php`and send requests every 200 ms if I don't get one of two possible responses "yes" or "no", resend request needed to get right answer no blank and not error.

If get "yes" "no" do functions.
when receiving responses, perform different actions

1. function after receiving yes
2. function after receiving no

Comment: Check out promises in JavaScript! They were created exactly for this problem you are having

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for here, but here is my method based on my own interpretation of your question using a call from GitHub's API. We are using fetch to pull the data. Our .then is our resolve, and our .catch is our reject.

```
const url = 'https://api.github.com/users'

const callApi = function(fetchUrl){
    fetchUrl = url
    fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json(); // Turn data to JSON
        })
        .then(data=>{ // If it was successful, this below will run
            console.log(data) // Do whatever you want with the data from the API here
        })
        .catch(err=>{ // If it was unsuccessful, this below will run
            console.log(err); // Console log the error
            setTimeout(callApi(url), 200); //If it failed, try again in 200ms
        })
}

callApi(url) // Initial function call
```

Some things to note: If you're using an API that limits the number of calls you can make in a day/month, this will eat up through those allotted requests really quickly.